# Jquery-UI hide and show effects don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I can't hide my div using some i.e. explode effect in jquery ui, It always slides down (or something like that), whatever effect I put as parameter in my code.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8rc3/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.rozwin').click(function(){
    $('#main').hide('explode');
    $('#main').show('explode');  
});  

<a href="" class="rozwin>hide and show</a>

<div id='main'>...</div>
```

Comment: When you create a concise example for us, please make sure the code is semantically correct. You've got four people looking at this and noticing the same glaring mistakes, and you've comment that it's not that way in the 'real' code. It shows a lack of effort in asking your question. Those of us that help do so because we like helping, but it's not fun trying to fix things that aren't really broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a bit wrong with this code.

This script src is missing the `http:`

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8rc3/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

You do not start your javascript with a `<script type="text/javascript">`, so all of your jQuery is interpreted as plain text.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

You are not preventing the default action of the click.

```
$('.rozwin').click(function(){
    $('#main').hide('explode');
    $('#main').show('explode');  
});
```

You do not enclose your `.ready()`...

Your anchor tag's class has no closing quote.

```
<a href="" class="rozwin>hide and show</a>

<div id='main'>...</div>
```

Here's the snippet with all the fixes it needs.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8rc3/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.rozwin').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#main').hide('explode');
            $('#main').show('explode');  
        });  
    });
</script>

<a href="" class="rozwin">hide and show</a>
<div id='main'>...</div>
```

Keep in mind that your show events won't work as expected because they're triggering too quickly, since you're not using it in the callback of `.hide()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/zq2Hz/

Comment: Still not working, i think that my jquery ui has some default effect set which i can't change - maybe some conflict or I'm not including some file?

Comment: You don't prevent the default action of the click, so it essentially refreshes your page, since you have an empty href.

Answer (score 0):

first line missed http:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and missed the end of $(document).ready(function(){

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('.rozwin').click(function(){
     $('#main').hide('explode');
     $('#main').show('explode');  
   });   
}); //at the end
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed closing braces and close quotes for class

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.rozwin').click(function(){
      $('#main').hide('explode');
      $('#main').show('explode');  
   }); 
});
<a href="" class="rozwin">hide and show</a>
```

Comment: I've got this, just didnt put in example : ) anyway, I dont think that can affect type of effect:)